# Amortized cost of insert/remove on min-heap

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, binary-heap, amortized-analysis

I ran into an interview question recently. no additional info is given into question (maybe default implementation should be used...)

> n arbitrary sequences of insert and remove operations on empty min heap
> (**location for delete element is known**) has amortized cost of:

A) insert O(1), remove O(log n)

B) insert O(log n), remove O(1)

The option (**B**) is correct.

I'm surprized when see answer sheet. i know this is tricky, maybe empty heap, maybe knowing location of elements for delete,... i dont know why (A) is false? Why (B) is true?

Comment: (A) Can be realized using a Fibonacci-Heap, check Wikipedia. Not sure why they say its false when it clearly exists.

Comment: @Zabuzard fibonacci heap is exactly reverse I thin ! am I wrong?

Comment: Right. Do you have more context? Why do they say its false when it clearly exists?

Comment: really I dont know !! is it possible to make a well and valid references compare as an answer. @Zabuzard you are so expert...

Comment: @Zabuzard Agreed about Fibonacci heaps. I had assumed (?) that the OP is referring to a classic binary heap, in which case answer (A) is wrong and answer (B) is correct, though on a second read I realize that the OP didn't actually specify that.

Comment: maybe because of location of element which need to deleted is known @Zabuzard maybe empty heap, there is trick sure...

Comment: @templatetypedef I agree with you. I think classic and general heap should be used because no other details provided.

Comment: No, I mean, are there any details provided about what you are actually supposed to do? Like, are you allowed to restrict the input domain? For example only sorted inputs? Or arbitrary inputs only?

Comment: templatetypedefs answer is absolutely right. You have to understand what ammortized cost means. If you previously have to waste a lot of time inserting, this will compensate an expensive removal cost in the analysis and dampen it down again. Mathematically, we are speaking about potential functions and the potential of the datastructure rises the more work you do. And then, an expensive remove call, can use that potential instead, resulting in a lower amortized cost.

Comment: @Zabuzard no not any restriction. just any type of heaps that be classic or general. what is your idea?

Comment: I was just trying to understand your question which lacks details. But you have gotten a good answer now.

Comment: Thanks @Zabuzard :) Exactly this is very tricky... Hard Interview with lack of information. Potential method is very nice if you can provide an answer too.

Answer (score 6):

When assigning amortized costs to operations on a data structure, you need to ensure that, for any sequence of operations performed, that the sum of the amortized costs is always at least as big as the sum of the actual costs of those operations.

So let's take Option 1, which assigns an amortized cost of O(1) to insertions and an amortized cost of O(log n) to deletions. The question we have to ask is the following: is it true that *for any* sequence of operations on an empty binary heap, the real cost of those operations is upper-bounded by the amortized cost of those operations? And in this case, the answer is no. Imagine that you do a sequence purely of *n* insertions into the heap. The actual cost of performing these operations can be Θ(n log n) if each element has to bubble all the way up to the top of the heap. However, the amortized cost of those operations, with this accounting scheme, would be O(n), since we did n operations and pretended that each one cost O(1) time. Therefore, this amortized accounting scheme doesn't work, since it will let us underestimate the work that we're doing.

On the other hand, let's look at Option 2, where we assign O(log n) as our amortized insertion cost and O(1) as our amortized remove cost. Now, can we find a sequence of n operations where the real cost of those operations exceeds the amortized costs? In this case, the answer is no. Here's one way to see this. We've set the amortized cost of an insertion to be O(log n), which matches its real cost, and so the only way that we could end up underestimating the total is with our amortized cost of a deletion (O(1)), which is lower than the true cost of a deletion. However, that's not a problem here. In order for us to be able to do a delete operation, we have to have previously inserted the element that we're deleting. The combined real cost of the insertion and the deletion is O(log n) + O(log n) = O(log n), and the combined amortized cost of the insertion and the deletion is O(log n) + O(1) = O(log n). So in that sense, pretending that deletions are faster doesn't change our overall cost.

A nice intuitive way to see why the second approach works but the first one doesn't is to think about what amortized analysis is all about. The intuition behind amortization is to charge earlier operations a bit more so that future operations appear to take less time. In the case of the second accounting scheme, that's exactly what we're doing: we're shifting the cost of the deletion of an element from the binary heap back onto the cost of inserting that element into the heap in the first place. In that way, since we're only shifting work backwards, the sum of the amortized costs can't be lower than the sum of the real costs. On the other hand, in the first case, we're shifting work *forward* in time by making deletions pay for insertions. But that's a problem, because if we do a bunch of insertions and then never do the corresponding deletions we'll have shifted the work to operations that don't exist.

Comment: always we should have real cost > amortized cost?

Comment: Yes, real costs should always be less than or equal to amortized costs. Otherwise, the amortized costs aren't very useful (for example, we could pretend everything costs O(1), but that won't match what we see if we actually use the data structure).

Comment: I'm surprized too !! if merge sort takes O(n log n) for n element, for one element we get O(log n) because divide by n. so real cost is bigger than amortized cost. am I wrong completely ?

Comment: Amortization typically applies in cases where you have multiple operations being performed one after the other and want to shuffle the costs across those operations. (For example, your question was about shifting the work around between different operations on a binary heap). You typically wouldn't think about doing an amortized analysis on mergesort, since mergesort is a single, end-to-end algorithm rather than a data structure with different operations that can be interleaved arbitrarily.

Comment: perfect. really nice

Comment: really very nice answer. five times reading... now again. one another question is there any valid book or references for upper bound tips for real cost and amortized cost? you are define it very nicely. you are so expert.

Comment: For an intuitive exploration of what amortization is about and some of the basic techniques, check [these slides](http://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs166/cs166.1206/lectures/07/Slides07.pdf). I also like [this book chapter](https://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/algorithms/notes/09-amortize.pdf) as reference.

Comment: very thanks. one point is doubt me. if we have option (C) as insert O(log n), remove O(log n) what about it. would you please consider this in your answer? thanks so much.

Comment: Based on what you've seen here, what do you think? Will that ever underestimate the total amount of work done on any sequence of operations?

Comment: so real cost O(n log n) insert O(n log n) delete. I try more to better underestand but because this case is comes to my mind is better help for underestanding.

Comment: informative answer. @LisaBerry I think this option is also works.

Comment: @templatetypedef maybe wrong... isnt it? this is more challenging I think both of them O(log n)?

Comment: I get confused. both case (log n) is real challenging too. I think these are same. would you please clarify me?

Comment: Your proposal for option (C) sets each operation's amortized cost equal to its real cost, so it's a perfectly valid set of amortized costs because it can't ever underestimate things. (Whether it's *useful* is a secondary question. ^_^)

Comment: please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65203302/best-amortized-option-for-insert-remove-element-on-min-heap

Comment: @templatetypedef would you please share your idea on why (B) is the best on respect to O(log n) as option (C) in new question?

Comment: I know one of options is tighter, so would you please consider an answer to new question?

Comment: would you please consider an answer to my question as you recommend after some days?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65203302/best-amortized-option-for-insert-remove-element-on-min-heap

Answer (score 1):

Because the heap is initially empty, you can't have more deletes than inserts.

An amortized cost of O(1) per deletion and O(log N) per insertion is exactly the same as an amortized cost of O(log N) for both inserts and deletes, because you can just count the deletion cost when you do the corresponding insert.

It does not work the other way around.  Since you *can* have more inserts than deletes, there might not be enough deletes to pay the cost of each insert.

Comment: if you one select one of them I means Option (C) both of them in O(log n) and Option (B), which one is better? is it good to open a new question for it now?

Comment: Option B and C would be the same in that case.  But for a test, option B is much better, because it shows that you understand the concept of amortization.

Comment: this is new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65203302/best-amortized-option-for-insert-remove-element-on-min-heap

Comment: I think you misunderstand.  Option B is not a better answer to the question, it's a better option to put on a test.  You need to consider what the test itself is *for*.

Comment: sure, you are right this is the logic that I open a new question. think these three option was present in one interview question. which one is a better one? sorry for my bad word selection.